# Running PowerShell script on debugging project

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2013

I have a C# project that relies on a few services. I've written a PowerShell script that checks if the services are running and starts them if they're not. I'm currently running the script manually, but it would be better if I could configure Visual Studio to run the script every time I start debugging the project.

I experimented with using the post-build events, but that only works (obviously) when the project has been changed and needs to be rebuilt. If there is a solution that allows me to run the PowerShell script regardless of whether the project is being rebuilt, that would be excellent.

Comment: Can't you choose the "Always" option for the "Run the post-build event" option appearing in the Build Events dialog?

Comment: As far as I understand, that still requires that the project is actually rebuilt.

Comment: One option might be to define a "dummy" console project, with just a line creating a new Process invoking your PowerShell script and use multiple the multiple startup projects option of Visual Studio : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165413.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I think that's the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement. This is what i did:

1. Installed the powershell tools from the [Visual Studio 2013 gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f65f845b-9430-4f72-a182-ae2a7b8999d7)
2. Added a project to the solution of the (newly installed) Powershell Project type
3. Added a Powershell script to start the services (in my case a Redis Server)
4. Added this project to the solution "set startup projects" (right-click on the Solution Explorer top level solution node) using the multiple startup projects setting